# Updating ProgressBar in a WPF MainWindow from another class (Delegate)

Tags: c#, wpf, delegates, progress-bar

The application parses CSV & XML files. As there are many files, the progress bar must be updated step by step. The WPF application is mainly for UI and related events. Another class actually implements the logic.

I have applied Delegate to update the value. The delegate receives the integer value for updating the progress bar, but the UI shows no changes.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
    <Grid Margin="20">
                <ProgressBar Height="50" Width="400" Minimum="0" Maximum="100"  Name="pbStatus" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=pbStatus, Path=Value, StringFormat={}{0:0}%}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
       Class2 fileConvert = new Class2();

       public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                fileConvert.UpdateProgress += UpdateProgress;

            }

    private void UpdateProgress(int ProgressPercentage)
            {
                Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(delegate ()
                {
                    pbStatus.Value = ProgressPercentage; 
                }));
            }
    private void BtnConvert_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       var newFiles = fileConvert.ProcessConvertInfo(allFiles, destiString);
    }
    }
```

Class2:

```
    public class Class2
    {
    public delegate void UpdateProgressDelegate(int ProgressPercentage);
    public event UpdateProgressDelegate UpdateProgress;

    public List<string> ProcessConvertInfo(string[] csvfiles, string destiPath)
    {
    foreach (string filePath in csvfiles)
    {
    //Progressbar value
     int i = Array.IndexOf(csvfiles, filePath);
    //Passing value to Delegate
    UpdateProgress(i++);
    }
    }
    }
```

This method below in MainWindow.xaml.cs receives the ProgressPercentage value for each iteration of the files in the list of another Class2 and is assigned to the progressbar Value.

```
    private void UpdateProgress(int ProgressPercentage)
            {
                Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(delegate ()
                {
                    pbStatus.Value = ProgressPercentage; 
                }));
            }
```

The progress bar does not show anything. I do not get any error. I am new to WPF. How can I find the problem?

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint on `pbStatus.Value = ProgressPercentage;` to check that `ProgressPercentage` contains the value you expect?

Comment: Yes did that. The expected value (ProgressPercentage) is received and assigned to pbStatus.Value

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks like it is blocking the UI thread. You might have deadlocked the application. But beside this, the code should work.

You should run the blocking operation asynchronously:

**Class2.cs**

```
public async Task<List<string>> ProcessConvertInfoAsync(string[] csvfiles, string destiPath)
{
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        foreach (string filePath in csvfiles)
        {
            //Progressbar value
            int i = Array.IndexOf(csvfiles, filePath);

            //Passing value to Delegate
            UpdateProgress(i++);
        }
        return csvfiles.ToList();
    });
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
private async void BtnConvert_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var newFiles = await fileConvert.ProcessConvertInfoAsync(allFiles, destiString);
}
```

To avoid the the code overhead and enable additional features, I recommend to use the [`Progress<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1?view=netframework-4.8) pattern. I think your approach is very close to it. The key of the `Progress<T>` class is, that it automatically captures the `SynchronizationContext` on construction. This eliminates the use of the Dispatcher. `Progress<T>` also enables cancellation of the progress reporting. Code will look expressive and clean as well.
This Microsoft article [Async in 4.5: Enabling Progress and Cancellation in Async APIs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/) explains in detail how to use it. The link is from the documentation of `Progress<T>`.

Comment: thank you for the elaborate explanation and the information link. I tried your approach and it worked :) I learnt quite a lot